# HTML Templating

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build this following HTML-Template:
[image: desired layout]

It's very easy, if I use the red containers 1-4, giving this syntax:

```
<div id="red-1">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div id="red-2">
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
<div id="red-3">
  <div>7</div>
</div>
<div id="red-4">
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/rbpep3ot/

But I want a solution where I wouldn't have to use the red DIVs, giving me this syntax:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/nhh4wdLr/1/

Is this even possible, given that the height of the whole thing is fixed, I can't think of a solution now. I don't want to use JS to create red DIVs on the fly.

The reason I don't want to use red DIVs is not because I didn't like them, it's more a theoretical question to expand my view on solving this kind of layout.

Thanks a lot in advance =)

Comment: Each box has a different width and height.. Then you must make a class for each box. It depends on if you want it responsive or fixed sizes.

Comment: Ah, sorry I might have been unclear. I do know that I must set width and height via CSS. But how do I float these DIVs correctly without using helper containers (aka the "red divs")?

For now, I'm totally OK with a non-responsive solution.

Comment: You could add absolute positioning to each of the divs, but for that they would need to have classes or ids. You could also work with :first-child etc. but that's super dirty. If you use positioning, your layout won't be responsive at all, but judging from the picture you drew you're not really looking for a responsive solution, right?

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't want to use absolute positioning, since the "div-worm" - as I call it - can have an undefined amount of divs. It might go up to 40 or 50, where I'd have to generate CSS automatically to have the correcty amount in my positioning, e.g. server side generated CSS: `.div-1 { left : $serverSideCalculatedValue$px;}`

Comment: Eh, I just posted an answer using absolute positioning. Ignore it then. I don't know of any way to achieve what you want without jquery.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the input tho =) I added 2 JSFiddles to make the question clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the question, gave me some really cool inspiration, i'll try something like that too, i'll answer if i find a solution for your proper problem. Sorry for non-helping comment ;D

Answer (score 1):

check this fiddle out:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="div1">1</div>
    <div class="div2">2</div>
    <div class="div5">5</div>
    <div class="div7">7</div>
    <div class="div8">8</div>
    <div class="div3">3</div>
    <div class="div4">4</div>
    <div class="div6">6</div>
    <div class="div9">9</div>
</div>

#container > div{
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jg0ufmx4/2/

You have to use absolute positioning of course, wish there was a better way

Comment: just been able to read the comments. you needed it without absolute positioning, so just ignore this, until i find a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wu0vbm1m/1/

Of course you need to adjust the height and width for the divs to use them as a real layout, this fiddle is just to give you an idea how to do it.

Basically, position each div absolutely:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Give your divs either a class or an idea to distinguish them by:

```
<div id="one">1</div>
```

You could also work with nth-child if you prefer that.

Then, proceed to position each of your divs according to your layout:

```
#two {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this also using **CSS Grid Layout**, although the support by browsers is miserable.

Take a look but make sure that you are using **IE10+**:
https://jsfiddle.net/nhh4wdLr/2/

```
body {
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    -ms-grid-rows: 35px 30px 30px;
}
.div-1 {
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
}
.div-2 {
    -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
}
.div-3 {
    -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
}
.div-4 {
    -ms-grid-column: 3;
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
}
.div-5 {
    -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
    -ms-grid-column: 4;
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
}
.div-6 {
    -ms-grid-column: 4;
    -ms-grid-row: 3;
}
.div-7 {
    -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
    -ms-grid-column: 5;
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
}
.div-8 {
    -ms-grid-column: 6;
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
}
.div-9 {
    -ms-grid-column: 6;
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
}
```